# I want to delete the trigger of the embed automatically how do I do it?

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

ex . trigger - hi , the bot responds with hello but I want the bot to automatically delete the trigger hi .

```
async def cd(ctx, message=None): 
 embed=discord.Embed(description= " \n ", color=3092790)
 embed.set_image(url= "cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/846254397210230806/…)
 ctx.message.delete 
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you're looking for commands or OG message, if OG message, you should using `ctx.message.delete`

Here's [the doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.delete) for you.

Comment: Hi lexy, consider read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, and edit your question. If you got some clue and start trying, you can try first then comment what problem occurred instead of ask before doing it.

Comment: @lexy Edit it in your question with `code block`, it's really hard to read.

Comment: @lexy I've test your code now. I'll works fine with the correct indent, await and function call. your `ctx.message.delete` missing these thing. Try to read the error message. and the doc describe the grammar very clearly `await delete(*, delay=None)`

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on how you have implemented that trigger. For example if you have added that trigger using `Discord.Bot.add_command` or using **bot cogs**, you can simply remove the command by calling `bot.remove_command(command_name). Or if you have added the trigger using` bot.add_listener`, then you can remove it by` bot.remove_listener( function, name_of_event)`.